# jQuery.each two keys simultaneously

Tags: jquery, foreach

I have this array:

```
row = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" ]
```

I want to iterate with something like:

```
row.each(function(key, value){ doStuff(key); });
```

But I want to grab "one" and "two" and after that "two" and "three" etc. in the same iteration.

This way I want to use jsPlumb to connect each key element with each other to create a sort of 'train' of elements.

I could manually ask for the `row[x+1]` each time (if you know what I mean), but I was wondering if there's an argument for `.each` or custom function to achieve this, so I could even grab 3 keys at the same time or more..

So I could do something like:

```
row.eachTwo(function(key, value){ doStuff(key[0], key[1]); });
```

Comment: You have answered the question yourself: That is the easiest solution, to use somethin like row[x + 1]

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [there](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). You can't do it with function `.each`. The best way is implement it yourself

Answer (score 1):

If you are satisfied with only processing two values at a time, I guess you could abuse the `reduce` method of Array:

```
​["one", "two", "three"].reduce(function(value1, value2) {
  doSomething(value1, value2);
  return value2;
});​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `.eachTwo()` function,

```
jQuery.fn.eachTwo = function(fn)
{
    var self = this;
    return this.each(function(key, el)
    {
        if (self.hasOwnProperty(key+1))
            fn.call(this,self[key],self[key+1],el)
    });
};

var row = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" ];

$(row).eachTwo(function(i,j){
    console.log(i+" "+j);
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/wnvEF/4/)

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I'll do it like this then:

```
oldKey = "one";

row.each(function(key, value){

if (key == oldKey)
{
    console.error("SAME");
}
else
{
    jsPlumb.connect({
                    source: key, 
                    target: oldKey,
                    anchor:"Continuous",
            });
}
oldKey = key; 
});
```

It's just that I only need to catch the first duplicate with `key == oldKey`, but I'm looking for a simpler, more elegant way, the `.next()` seemed nice and simple, but won't work on Arrays or simple Objects..